# How to make the mysql query using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Below is the table structure I have

```
user_id    quote_id    bill_type(2=>proforma,1=>invoice)
474        676          2
674        676          2
474        676          1
445        680          2
422        120          2
411        240          2
411        240          2
410        240          2
410        240          1
```

Basically in my portal we have  Buyer and Seller(*user_id*), and both of them can buy and sell with a specific *quote_id* as shown in the above table. A specific pair of buyer and seller can have multiple *quote_id*. (you can consider the case of Amazon where specific buyer can purchase multiple products from a specific seller. here product will be *quote_id*)

Here *bill_type* refers to the invoice(1) or proforma(2). Invoice will be sent to the user only once and proforma can be sent multiple times for a specific *quote_id*. Now the problem is that I want to return the data such that users whose invoice is not yet generated for a specific quote_id should be returned.

If we consider the above case then returned data should be:

```
user_id    quote_id    bill_type(2=>proforma,1=>invoice)
    674        676          2
    445        680          2
    422        120          2
    411        240          2
```

This are the users whose bill is not yet generated for a specific *quote_id*.

The query that I have managed to make so far is:

```
select *, GROUP_CONCAT(bill_type) as bt,GROUP_CONCAT(user_id)
  from quote 
  GROUP BY quote_id
```

Now I am deleting the user whose invoice is generated with help of program. but that is not the right way to do I need the query to achieve this.

Comment: remove " *, "  alter select from query

Comment: @areklipno yes, but still I will not be able to get the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause, to check that there is no matching invoice sent for a particular `user_id/quote_id` combination:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q1.user_id, q1.quote_id, q1.bill_type
FROM quote q1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM quote q2
                  WHERE q2.user_id = q1.user_id AND q2.quote_id = q2.quote_id AND q2.bill_type = 1)
```

Output:

```
user_id  quote_id  bill_type
674      676       2 
445      680       2 
422      120       2 
411      240       2
```

The `DISTINCT` on the `SELECT` ensures you don't get multiple rows in situations where more than one proforma invoice is sent (e.g. combination 411/240).

To deal with the case where quote_id is NULL and you don't want those lines in the output, change the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q1.user_id, q1.quote_id, q1.bill_type
FROM quote q1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM quote q2
                  WHERE q2.user_id = q1.user_id AND q2.quote_id = q2.quote_id AND q2.bill_type = 1)
    AND q1.quote_id IS NOT NULL
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bda00/2)

Comment: I have tried doing the above on my dataset, in this rows with quote_id as null is also coming. there are some null values in my dataset. how can I limit them as well

Comment: @NikhilGupta I've updated my query and [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bda00/2) to deal with NULL values of `quote_id`. I've assumed you wouldn't send an invoice if there is no quote, if that's not the case let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select distinct
  t1.user_id,
  t1.quote_id,
  t1.bill_type
from
  quote t1
left join  quote t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
                       t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
                       t2.bill_type = 1
where
  t1.bill_type = 2 and 
  t2.bill_type is null;
```

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef1af/10/0)

Comment: I am unable to understand why you have done t2.bill_type is null

Comment: Doing this we exclude rows with bill_type=2 which does have corresponding row with bill_type=1. I hope this sheds some light